# Python Facebook login

Tags: python, facebook

How can I make a Python script which checks if I have logged in the Facebook? If I haven't, it should log me in.

Comment: That depends very much on your platform. What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this, since much(all) of Pythons API is written in Javascript/PHP.

Comment: I'm a very beginner in coding. What is a platform? I'm using Linux Mint Helena, Firefox 3.6.11, Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) [GCC 4.4.1] on linux2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being "logged in" to Facebook (or any system for that matter) is generally a contract between the server and the client - and not just a "flipped bit" on the server.

As an example, if you log into Facebook on you phone - you can't then pull up Facebook on your desktop machine and be logged in.

In short - no, I don't think so.